# flyway + gradle + spring boot configuration

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, flyway

How can I configure flyway in build.gradle to get url ,username, password from other properties file?

Instead of this:

```
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db'
    user = 'a'
    password = 'a'
    locations = ['filesystem:db/migration']
}
```

something like this:

```
flyway {
    path = ['filesystem:src/main/resources/data-access.properties']
    locations = ['filesystem:db/migration']
}
```

Comment: gradle scripts contain groovy code. groovy code can read properties files. You could also do it the other way: put the values i your gradle script, and insert them in the properties file at build time, to avoid duplication.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot then why run flyway from the script? Why aren't you letting boot run the migrations?

Comment: I second what Deinum said.  The best way to keep the flyway properties is in the application.properties or .yml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ext.flywayProps = new Properties()
flywayProps.load(new FileInputStream(this.projectDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/resources/data-access.properties"))
```

In the root of your build script, it will load a properties file into local variable of `Properties` type. After that you can use this properties the way you need it, like so for example:

```
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://flywayProps['dbIp']:flywayProps['dbPort']/db'
    user = flywayProps['dbUsername']
    password = flywayProps['dbPassword']
    locations = ['filesystem:db/migration']
}
```

And in your `data-access.properties` you need to specify it as follows:

```
dbIp=localhost
dbPort=5432
dbUsername=a
dbPassword=a
```

Comment: good example, thanks bro